# Concatenate multiple xml rows into one

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, concatenation

### Problem:

I want to get changes from an sql server to be printed into a (probably big) xml file.
The Sql-Server has ChangeTracking enabled to identify the entities with the changes.
Therefore i have written three `Scalar-valued Functions` which can generate the appropriate XML for a single entity.

GenerateAccountXml( int AccountId )

GenerateDeviceXml( int DeviceId )

GenerateServiceXml( int ServiceId )

Also i have three `Table-valued Function` which returns the Entity-Ids for a specific
ChangeTracking Number.

GetAccountChangeSets( bigint changeTrackingId )

GetDeviceChangeSets( bigint changeTrackingId )

GetServiceChangeSets( bigint changeTrackingId )

Finally i make a call like this:

```
select

(
    select
    (
        select [dbo].GenerateServiceXml( CT.ServiceId )
        from [dbo].GetServiceChangeSets( 22000 ) CT
    ) FOR XML PATH( 'Services' ), TYPE
),

(
    select
    (
        select [dbo].GenerateDeviceXml( CT.DeviceId )
        from [dbo].GetDeviceChangeSets( 22000 ) CT
    ) FOR XML PATH( 'Devices' ), TYPE
),

(
    select
    (
        select [dbo].GenerateAccountXml( CT.AccountId ) )
        from [dbo].GetAccountChangeSets( 22000 ) CT
    ) FOR XML PATH( 'Accounts' ), TYPE
)

FOR XML PATH( 'Changes' ), TYPE
```

This works as long as the `GetXXXChangeSets` Functions return only one EntityId for each Entity, but at the moment i get multiple XML-Rows for each entity. Now the Problem is the following error-message:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery 
follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

I have tried the `STUFF` command, but it only accepts a varchar. When i convert the output in a varchar(max) the `<` and `>` sign are replaced.

Are there other solutions for this problem?

Comment: Does `GetXXChangeSets` return actual XML data or is it a string?

Comment: @JNK `GetXXXChangeSets` returns the id of the entity which has changes and `GenerateXXXXml` returns the changes as `xml` for a given entity id

Comment: OK...I have an idea then.  answer coming up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the engine should handle this and give you multiple XML nodes if you change the query slightly.  If you want to have a root node for the element collections you may need to change the `XML PATH('Service')` to say 'XML PATH (''), ROOT('Services')` which will combine all the rows into a single node.

Essentially I think the issue is you have one too many nested subselects.  The built in `FOR XML` can handle multiple rows in a nested `SELECT` expression just fine.

```
select

(   select [dbo].GenerateServiceXml( CT.ServiceId )
    from [dbo].GetServiceChangeSets( 22000 ) CT
    FOR XML PATH( 'Services' ), TYPE
),

(
    select [dbo].GenerateDeviceXml( CT.DeviceId )
    from [dbo].GetDeviceChangeSets( 22000 ) CT
    FOR XML PATH( 'Devices' ), TYPE
),

(
    select [dbo].GenerateAccountXml( CT.AccountId ) )
    from [dbo].GetAccountChangeSets( 22000 ) CT
    FOR XML PATH( 'Accounts' ), TYPE
)

FOR XML PATH( 'Changes' ), TYPE
```

Comment: Perfect, works exactly like i want it to =) Haha, but first of all i thought you made a re-post of my sql, because the changes are REALLY slightly ^^

Comment: Yes it's a very minor change.  I'm not sure why you had that additional `SELECT` but that created some issues :)

Comment: I was trying a lot. I can't even remember my inital statement. Maybe it was just another try, but now it works. Thanks again.